# Counter for items in an inventory using iterators

Tags: c++, vector

I'm somewhat new to vectors and iterators and I'm trying to figure out how to display an *amount* of items using an iterator. One example would be you have 5 apples. I would want it to output "5x Apple" or something of that sort. I have no idea how one might accomplish this. Here's a simple code that has the user put in a string to add to the inventory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string item;

vector<string> inventory;
vector<string>::iterator iter;

int main()
{
    while(true){
       cin >> item;
       inventory.push_back(item);

       cout << "INVENTORY:\n";

       for(iter = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); iter++)
       cout << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to make an inventory system for a game. That's why I thought i may need an iterator. If there's a better way to make an inventory system than using an iterator, please let me know. Apologies, i should have clarified.

Comment: What does this have to do with iterators?

Comment: It's using an iterator, I thought that was enough to consider it having something to do with iterators. Maybe it's more to do with vectors? You be the judge.

Comment: Why are you using an iterator at all here? And where is the `5` for "5x Apple" coming from? It's really unclear what the question is

Comment: @UnholySheep It was just an example of something I might want output; were the user to input "apple" 5 times it would output "5x apple".

Comment: Global variables are usually a bad thing, somethig you should use as little as possible. The smaller is the scope of a variable, the easier to manutain the code. this is even more true for an iterator. I can't imagine any scenario where a global variable of type iterator can be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to simplify this is to sort the items in the inventory.  That will bring the identical ones together, which simplifies counting them.  Start at the beginning, count the number of consecutive items that match the current one, display it, and continue with the first non-matching one.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string item;
    std::vector<std::string> inventory;

    while (true) {
       std::cin >> item;
       if (item  == "quit") return 0;

       inventory.push_back(item);
       std::sort(inventory.begin(), inventory.end());

       std::cout << "INVENTORY:\n";

       auto current = inventory.begin();
       while (current != inventory.end()) {
          int count = 1;
          auto probe = current + 1;
          while (probe != inventory.end() && *probe == *current) { 
              ++count;
              ++probe;
          }
          std::cout << count << "x " << *current << '\n';
          current = probe;
       }
       std::cout.flush();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In more detail, if your inventory is {"orange", "apple", "orange"}, then the sort will rearrange the order to {"apple", "orange", "orange"}.  Note that the identical ones are together.

Now the iterator `current` starts at the beginning ("apple").  We set `count` to 1 because we know there's at least 1.  We set the iterator `probe` to point to the next item ("orange").  Since the value at `probe` doesn't match the value at `current`, the inner loop does nothing.  We print `count` and the current item ("apple").  We continue by setting `current` to `probe`, because, at this point, `probe` will point to the first item that didn't match the current one.

On the second iteration, `current` refers to the first "orange".  We reset `count` to 1 and start `probe` at the next item ("orange").  Since the values at match, we increment `count` (now 2) and advance `probe` (now at the end of the inventory).  We print `count` (2) and the current item ("orange"), and set `current` to `probe` (end of the list).  The outer loop condition sees we're at the end of the inventory, so the loop terminates.

Comment: You, sir, are a GENIUS. This works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An iterator lets you iterate through a container, but it does not do any counting for you.

A container's `size()` tells you how many items are in the container, but if you have different types of items then you have to count them yourself.

For instance, say you have 4 `"apple"` and 1 `"orange"`.

You have to look at each item entered and count it as needed, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> inventory;
int numApples = 0;
int numOranges = 0;
int numOther = 0;

int main()
{
    string item;

    while (cin >> item)
    {
        inventory.push_back(item);

        if (item == "apples")
            ++numApples;
        else if (item == "orange")
            ++numOranges;
        else
            ++numOther;
    }

    cout << "INVENTORY:\n";

    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); ++iter)
        cout << *iter << endl;

    /* or, if you are using C++11 or later:
    for (string &s : inventory)
        cout << s << endl;
    */

    cout << "# apples: " << numApples << endl;
    cout << "# oranges: " << numOranges  << endl;
    cout << "# other: " << numOther << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or, you might consider using [`std::count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> inventory;

bool isApple(const string &s) { return (s == "apple"); }
bool isOrange(const string &s) { return (s == "orange"); }
bool isOther(const string &s) { return !(isApple(s) || isOrange(s)); }

int main()
{
    string item;

    while (cin >> item)
        inventory.push_back(item);

    cout << "INVENTORY:\n";

    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = inventory.begin(); iter != inventory.end(); ++iter)
        cout << *iter << endl;

    /* or, if you are using C++11 or later:
    for (string &s : inventory)
        cout << s << endl;
    */

    cout << "# apples: " << count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), isApple) << endl;
    cout << "# oranges: " << count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), isOrange) << endl;
    cout << "# other: " << count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), isOther) << endl;

    /* or, if you are using C++11 or later:
    cout << "# apples: " << count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), [](auto &s){ return (s == "apple"); }) << endl;
    cout << "# oranges: " << count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), [](auto &s){ return (s == "orange"); }) << endl;
    cout << "# other: " << count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), [](auto &s){ return (s != "apple") && (s != "orange"); }) << endl;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update**: based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540058/) you posted, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> other_inventory;
int numApples = 0;
int numOranges = 0;

int main()
{
    string item;

    while (cin >> item)
    {
        if (item == "apples")
            ++numApples;
        else if (item == "orange")
            ++numOranges;
        else
            other_inventory.push_back(item);
    }

    cout << "INVENTORY:\n";

    if (numApples > 0)
        cout << "# apples: " << numApples << endl;

    if (numOranges > 0)
        cout << "# oranges: " << numOranges  << endl;

    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = other_inventory.begin(); iter != other_inventory.end(); ++iter)
        cout << *iter << endl;

    /* or, if you are using C++11 or later:
    for (string &s : other_inventory)
        cout << s << endl;
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I implement size() and/or count_if() into the code?

Comment: They are part of the standard C++ vector type. I think you need to learn a lot more before attempting this task.

Comment: You wouldn't use lambda functions instead as a normal course? `count_if(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), [](auto s) { return s == "apple" })` ? (Would `auto` work in this context? I think a proper answer would be the equivalent of C# LINQ `GroupBy`.

Comment: @NetMage a lambda will also work. I just prefer to not assume everyone is using a C++11 or later compiler.

Answer (score -1):

```
inventory.size()
```

returns the number of items in your vector.

I don't see how you would need an iterator for that task.